# How to access and change Python arrays with logical operators?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I would like to know how to do the following MATLAB statement in Python:

```
X(0.80 < X & X < 1) = 1;
```

This statement says: `Put 1 in the indices where the value of X is between 0.8 and 1`.

I am looking for a solution in NumPy arrays of Python lists.

Thanks.

I tried:

```
X[X > 0.8 and X < 1]
```

but it says: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with order-of-operation, so just use parentheses:

```
X[(X > 0.8) & (X < 1)]
```

Note that I'm also using the ampersand instead of `and`.